# Change background color of window title in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to customize the background color of a `DialogFragment` I created. By default, when I set the window title text, I get white text on a black background. How can I change this to my own colors?

Looking at similar questions I find that some people recommend creating a custom style in `styles.xml`. I have tried this but haven't succeeded so far.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_planner_fragment, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), null));

        //getDialog().setTitle("Fubar");
        //getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MyDialog);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        return view;
    }
```

In `styles.xml` I have tried:

```
<style name="MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/md_orange_900</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Have a look at this](http://web.archive.org/web/20120203153326/http://blog.androgames.net/10/custom-android-dialog/). It shows you step-by-step exactly what you want to do: